# DerivedState from prop

Tags: reactjs

My component has a derivedState from a prop.

useEffect should override the state if the prop changes and actually only runs if needed.
But React is warning that value has to be part of the dependency array.

```
function App() {
  let [defValue, setDefValue] = useState("default");
  return (
    <div>
      defaultValue:
      <input value={defValue} onChange={(e) => setDefValue(e.target.value)} />
      <Derived defValue={defValue} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Derived(props) {
  let [value, setValue] = useState(props.defValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect runs");
    if (value !== props.defValue) {
      setValue(props.defValue);
    }
  }, [props.defValue]);

  return (
    <div>
      value:
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

But if I add value to the dependency array, useEffect runs every time and resets the value.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect runs");
    if (value !== props.defValue) {
      setValue(props.defValue);
    }
  }, [value, props.defValue]);
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this one of those situations where
`//eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` is needed? See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880#issuecomment-485912528

Answer (score 0):

If your code is going to remain as it is, you will need to add an `eslint-disable` to suppress the warning. But there's actually a better option here: use the function version of `setValue`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setValue(prev => {
    if (prev !== props.defValue) {
      return props.defValue;
    } else {
      return prev;
    }
  });
}, [props.defValue]);
```

With this change you no longer depend on `value`, so the lint rule will not complain. And at the same time you eliminate the possibility of `value` being stale.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think, that yours is equal to `useEffect(() => {setValue(props.defValue)}, [props.defValue])`, because setValue and therefore rerender is always happen. The `if(...)` was to prevent rerender.